# Web Activity in Microsoft Data Factory Azure - GET Headers and passing parameters (currently showing null)

Tags: azure, rest, get, header

I am using Azure Data Factory (web interface) to call a 3rd party API.
When passing a postcode, it returns me the postcode and city as JSON.
There is no authentication.

API endpoint:

```
https://example.com/endpoint?postcode=NNN234
```

So, I get the URL in the web activity as

```
https://example.com/endpoint
```

Method is set as GET

The headers:

```
name: postcode 
value: NNN234
```

Upon running the activity, the output is as follows:

```
 "Response": "{\"postcode\":null,\"city\":null}"
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I confusing headers with URL parameters? How do I fix this in Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you are getting the headers mixed up with the URL. Are you using the 'copy' activity or the 'web' activity in data factory? As there are some slight differences, but either way for this request you do not need to set any headers ;-)

Say for example you have a JSON data set called 'Json1' as your source in the 'copy' activity, like so:-

[image]

Then open your 'Json1' data set and set the relative url to '?postcode=NNN234'. Note that you'll need to set the 'base url' part in the linked service you're using - you can't override this setting in the dataset unfortunately. Set the the base url in the linked service to 'https://example.com/endpoint' if you haven't already. See below for data set (note I've scrubbed out some of my own settings),:-

[image]

That should be it (apart from setting the 'sink' settings to whatever you need them to be)